# NetSuite Saved Search on Sales Order Sub-list (Related Records)

Tags: search, netsuite, saved-searches

I'm trying to create a Saved Search that includes all Sales Orders and their Sub-List related records (ie. Invoices, Revenue Arrangments, etc.)

I've looked for the fields in the SuiteScript Record Browser and had our Admin run a Custom Fields report.  But they don't exist in either location.

Any thoughts on how to run a Saved Search for Sales Orders that includes the associated Invoices, Revenue Arrangements, etc?

Answer (score 2):

On **Transaction Saved Search**  you can give criteria/filter as  'Type' as 'SalesOrder , Invoice ' etc... 
There is a filed in Invoice called **Created From** or **Created From Fields..**. You can use this field to map to Sales Record .
And finally Group the Result

Answer (score 1):

Try "applying transaction" or "apply to transaction", you should be able to extract the related transaction.  Also, this should generated multiple main line transactions.